# Need to access cookie cross website

Tags: jquery, cookies

I had create cookies on one of my website www.abc.com, I want to access these cookies on my another website on www.abc1.com.

Is it possible to access cookies on cross website on client browser.
I am using jquery for this

Comment: what have you tried? it seems to me that in the first google search, 6th or 7th result talks about how facebook is doing it, using iframe

Answer (score 5):

Nope you cannot do this, it designed this way for security.

You can access cookies across sub domains for a common parent domain but not across two separate ones.

Ex: `learn.abc.com` and `teach.abc.com` could share cookies but not `www.abc1.com` and `www.abc.com`

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for security reasons.